# Reverting a contract, is it possible?

Tags: smart-contract

Lets assume this highly hypothetical scenario.

For some reason I issue a token and do the airdrop overnight, just to realize that there is a spelling error in the token symbol/ticker after 8hr.  Is it possible to revert it, recover the loss and do it again?

How about sending large sums of EOS to someone by making a coding error in a smart contract ?

Answer (score 1):

Custom token balance is stored on table on your smart contract. SO I think this way should works.

1. Provide method to empty table to get ram back.( all users have received airdrop will be rollbacked)
2. Update your smart contract and deploy it.

Comment: Thanks, any code example ?

Comment: Yes, you need to upgrade your contract, add an empty method to clear all the data to get ram back, if you don't care about the cost, you don't need to upgrade it, and create a new token instead.